# Rails migration schema issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

In my rails App I have three models/tables in the database (users, registrants, events). I was setting up some Capybara/RSpec tests when I ran into an issue saying it could not find the events table.

Now the events model has been working fine, I've been able to create events, go into the rails console and query things such as Events.all or Events.find(1). What is confusing me is my schema. My schema has

```
create_table "registrations", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    ...
end

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
    ...
end
```

But there is no reference to the events table. It's been some time since I generated the model for Events but here is the migration:

```
class CreateEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:events) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :location

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I have ran commands such as rake db:reset and rake db:migrate to make sure all my migrations are current. Any ideas why the events table is not in the schema?

**UPDATE:**
So I've deleted the DB and Schema and began migrating each migration one at a time. The events table is there when I run the migration to create it, but after I run the following command the table disappears from the schema:

```
class AddingAssociationsToEventsUserModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :events, :belongs_to, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

Here is the migration being run:

```
rake db:migrate:redo VERSION=20150518132834
== 20150518132834 AddingAssociationsToEventsUserModels: migrating =============
-- add_column(:events, :belongs_to, :user, {:index=>true})
   -> 0.0006s
== 20150518132834 AddingAssociationsToEventsUserModels: migrated (0.0006s) ====
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the issue was a mistake in my migration file. Here is what I changed my migration to:

```
class AddingAssociationsToEventsUserModels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :events, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

Now the events table is in my Schema and the test can find the table and is passing!

Answer (score 3):

That's because `test` database and `development` database are not matched.

Run:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:drop && rake db:create && rake db:migrate
```

or

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:test:prepare
```

or

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:reset
```

Any of the above should work.

Comment: quick questions, does that just explain why the test fails? Because I am still confused why the table wouldn't be showing in the db/schema.rb file

Comment: Test and Development share the same schema, but not the same database. You need to match both databases with the same schema. When you run console or server rails uses development as default, and when you run migrate, rails uses development. Your test helper might not be properly configured and that is why is not recreating the database each time you run it.

Comment: So I tried your suggestions and that didn't work. I deleted my DB and Schema and started migrating each migration one at a time. So the event table is there until a certain migration, then after that migration it will fail. I will add the migration to my question and maybe you can help me!